# How to disable Windows 10 pop ups after processing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows

Whenever I run any processing algorithm in QGIS, after it finishes I get Windows 10 pop-ups (notofications in lower-right corner) which says that the processing is finished. It is very annoying, particularly when I run very quick and simple algorithms, because it makes QGIS window out of focus and to get back to work I have to close the pop-up first.

How can I disable Windows 10 notifications for QGIS?

Comment: Upgrade to QGIS 3.4 -- they only show for long running tasks on 3.4

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? The behavior has changed in 3.4.

Comment: This is QGIS 3.2. I use this version because 3.4 causes some problems with Python while using GRASS algorithms

Comment: Aaaaah! then my answer did not capture the real cause of this issue, sorry. Will you guys post it as answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the Windows Settings menu by pressing the Windows Key and “I”
2. Click on "System" (Display, notifications, apps, power)
3. Click “Notifications & Actions” menu
4. Wait a few seconds until Windows finds and lists all apps which uses "Notifications"
5. Scroll down list of apps and find **QGIS**
6. Turn it off
7. Enjoy!

Comment: The problem is there is no QGIS on this list. The pop-up looks like this: https://imgur.com/CUAZYSh

Comment: @KaRolthas Could you translate it for me to understand what it is?

Comment: "Zadanie ukończone" is "Task is finished" and "Punkty wzdłuż geometrii" is the name of algorithm "Points along geometry"

Comment: Thanks @KaRolthas Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it by my quick tests.