# Suppress QgsTask "Task Complete" notification

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, windows-10, tasks

I'm following the [Extending QgsTask](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html#extending-qgstask) example to create a custom `QgsTask`.

However, I don't want it to display the `Task Complete` notification<sup>*</sup> every time the task completes successfully.

Is it possible (preferably using PyQGIS) to suppress the "Task Complete"  notification?

<sup>*</sup> In Windows 10 at least, the notification appears in the bottom right of the screen above the time (with a ding!).

Comment: you need change this parameters in your windows, check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304626/how-to-disable-windows-10-pop-ups-after-processing-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks @Fran Raga, though I'd much prefer to do it specifically for this task (e.g. using PyQGIS), rather than for *ALL* QGIS notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there's no API available to control the notification on a task-by-task basis (as of QGIS 3.8)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer nonetheless!